# How can I pass a string literal to a method for a click event

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to pass a string literal to a method for a click handler.

```
<button (click)="changeLanguage("en")">EN</button>
```

It does not work the way it is above. How can this be achieved?

Comment: <button onclick="changeLanguage('en')">EN</button>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need single and double quotes:

```
<button (click)="changeLanguage('en')">EN</button>
```

proof it works:

```
yoloMcLogger(yolo)
{
   console.log(yolo)
}

<button (click)="yoloMcLogger('YOLO')">
    YOLO
</button>
```

Comment: @connexo why will that not work? The question is about `angular2`

Comment: Yes it will just made an example, thought I was cracking up.

Comment: What a stupid syntax. So Angular forces you to produce invalid HTML, right?

Comment: Its valid html, it has nothing to do with angular https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: It's ***invalid HTML***. `(click)` is **not** a valid attribute. Neither in HTML 3.2, nor in HTML 4 (which you referenced and noone uses any more), nor in HTML 5.

Comment: yoloMcLogger(yolo) is a typescript class member(check the tags it says typescript and angular2) with the rest omitted?? The original question was nothing to do with angular custom attributes it was about misuse of quotes when trying to pass a plain old string as an argument.

Comment: @connexo angular2 doesn't force you to use invalid html. You can still use the `data-on-event` notation. But lots of people prefer the more semantic syntax, which i totally understand. HTML validation in combination with custom attributes is overrated if you ask me

Answer (score -4):

The attribute is "onclick".

`<button onclick="changeLanguage('en')">EN</button>`

Comment: No it is not, this is angular 2 where the event is called `(click)`